# How Do I call individual radio buttons on if else statement when buttons are created dynamically?

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement, radio-button

I have the code below, in `button1_Click` from someone in this forum, I cannot figure out what the next step is. Let say I have 4 radio buttons can someone show me an example of how to use the if else statement to each individual radio buttons based on their individual if else statement when I click button2?

```
var list = new List<string>
{
    "First radio text", "Second radio text", "Third radio text", "And so on"
};

this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    var r = new RadioButton();
    r.Text = list[i];
    r.Tag = i;
    r.Name = string.Format("r{0}", i);
    r.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    r.CheckedChanged += r_CheckedChanged;
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(r);
    r.BringToFront();
}
this.panel1.ResumeLayout(true);
```

Comment: Could you be more clear? What if-else statement? What exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: if radio button1 is selected do this, if radio button2 is selected do that and so on, When I tried coding if else on button2 every buttons responds to the same if else statement that is coded only for radio button1. if I have and if else statement for radio button3 why is the is statement responding to radio button1 or 2 or 3 also?.

Comment: In other words, if radio button1 is checked messagebox "Hello world" fine. then if I check in other radio buttons it also fires the messabox that is suppose to only be for radio button1.

Comment: How are you checking the radioButtons in the CheckedChanged event? You must get the sender and check its name to compare which radionbutton fired that event.

Comment: Yes Kyore you are correct. I'm a beginner, could you show me a code example on button2 click event please?

Answer (score 0):

You can check which radio button sent the event by its name:

```
private void r_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RadioButton radio = sender as RadioButton;

            if (radio.Name == "r1")
                MessageBox.Show("Radio 1 checked changed to: " + radio.Checked);
            else if (radio.Name == "r2")
                MessageBox.Show("Radio 2 checked changed to: " + radio.Checked);
            else if (radio.Name == "r3")
                MessageBox.Show("Radio 3 checked changed to: " + radio.Checked);
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Unknow radio button");
        }
```